# simple animation using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, animation, tkinter

I have a simple code to visualise some data using tkinter. A button click is bound to the function that redraws the next "frame" of data. However, I'd like to have the option to redraw automatically with a certain frequency. I'm very green when it comes to GUI programming (I don't have to do a lot for this code), so most of my tkinter knowledge comes from following and modifying examples. I guess I can use root.after to achieve this, but I'm not quite sure I understand how from other codes. The basic structure of my program is as follows:

```
# class for simulation data
# --------------------------------

def Visualisation:

   def __init__(self, args):
       # sets up the object


   def update_canvas(self, Event):
       # draws the next frame

       canvas.delete(ALL)

       # draw some stuff
       canvas.create_........


# gui section
# ---------------------------------------

# initialise the visualisation object
vis = Visualisation(s, canvasWidth, canvasHeight)

# Tkinter initialisation
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = canvasWidth, height = canvasHeight)

# set mouse click to advance the simulation
canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', vis.update_canvas)

# run the main loop
root.mainloop()
```

Apologies for asking a question which I'm sure has an obvious and simple answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic pattern for doing animation or periodic tasks with Tkinter is to write a function that draws a single frame or performs a single task. Then, use something like this to call it at regular intervals:

```
def animate(self):
    self.draw_one_frame()
    self.after(100, self.animate)
```

Once you call this function once, it will continue to draw frames at a rate of ten per second -- once every 100 milliseconds. You can modify the code to check for a flag if you want to be able to stop the animation once it has started. For example:

```
def animate(self):
    if not self.should_stop:
        self.draw_one_frame()
        self.after(100, self.animate)
```

You would then have a button that, when clicked, sets `self.should_stop` to `False`

Comment: Many thanks Bryan; I'd done something similar but had somehow one of my event bindings was messing things up. All working now.

Comment: the first version causes the error maximum recursion depth reach if allowed to run indefinitely

Comment: @rahultyagi: no, it's impossible to exceed the maximum recursion depth because it's not a recursive function. At least, not in the literal sense. The function doesn't call itself, it merely schedules itself to run again in the future. The stack depth never exceeds 1.

Comment: yeah i  just read about that in another post totally got confused :)

Comment: @rahultyagi the stack depth would increase if you called the function by using parentheses (either empty or passing an argument). To solve that either lop off the parentheses or use a lambda function so the passed function is not called right away and not inside itself.

Comment: @AlecKeyserWhite: _"the stack depth would increase if you called the function by using parentheses"_ - while true, this answer does not suggest calling the function with parenthesis so it doesn't have a problem with a growing stack.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, I just wanted to follow up with Rahul on how to fix _if_ you need to pass arguments. You're solution works perfectly, but I added this clarification for others looking for help and encountering that error when adapting your solution to their needs.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add Bryan's answer. I don't have enough rep to comment.

Another idea would be to use `self.after_cancel()` to stop the animation.

So...

```
def animate(self):
    self.draw_one_frame()
    self.stop_id = self.after(100, self.animate)

def cancel(self):
    self.after_cancel(self.stop_id)
```