# 'Nonetype' object not callable when calling animation of object in tkinter

Tags: python, animation, tkinter

I've been using this as a template:

[Blobs Animation](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-animation.htm)

and pretty much the only difference I can find is he uses the line:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

whereas I use the line

```
import Tkinter as Tk
```

I thought I accounted for this by making all my calls to Tkinter modules as Tk.(Blob.py equivalent).  I can this blob animation example to run, but my program gets the error:

```
'Nonetype' object not callable
```

on the line:

```
allStars[i] = allStars[i]()
```

from my code below (this particular line is in the last block of code):

```
class Star:

    def __init__(self, canvas, xy, delta):

        self.canvas = canvas
        self.delta = delta

        self.id = self.canvas.create_rectangle(
            xy[0],xy[1],
            xy[0]+starSize,xy[1]+starSize,
            fill='white'
            )


    def __call__(self):
        return self.down

    def down(self):

        xy = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if xy[1] >= gameScreenHeight:
            x2 = random.randint(1,gameScreenWidth)
            y2 = 0;
            self.canvas.coords(self.id,x2,y2)
        else:
            self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, self.delta)


root = Tk.Tk()
root.title("Stars")
root.resizable(0,0)
TkPlacement = "%dx%d%+d%+d" % (gameScreenWidth, gameScreenHeight, 10*starSize, heightOffset)
root.geometry(TkPlacement)

frame = Tk.Frame(root, bd = 5, relief=Tk.SUNKEN)
frame.pack()

space = Tk.Canvas(frame, width = gameScreenWidth, height = gameScreenHeight, cursor = 'plus')
space.pack()
space.create_rectangle(0,0,gameScreenWidth,gameScreenHeight,fill="black")



allStars = [
    Star(space, (10,30),3),
    Star(space, (15,60),3),
    Star(space, (80,50),5)
    ]

#N = 99;

#for i in range(N):
#   x1 = random.randint(1,gameScreenWidth)
#   y1 = random.randint(1,gameScreenHeight)
#   aStar = Star(space, (x1,y1), 3)
#   allStars.append(aStar)

root.update()

try:
    while 1:
        for i in range(len(allStars)):
            allStars[i] = allStars[i]()
            root.update_idletasks() # redraw
        root.update() # process events
except Tk.TclError:
    pass # to avoid errors when the window is closed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`down()` returns `None` (implicitly); and the first time through your infinite loop you're replacing everything in `allStars` with it.

`allStars[i] = allStars[i]()` is probably not what you want, although it's not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish with that.

Comment: ah, I see.  He uses a return in his call functions that I totally neglected.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Early in your code you set `allStars[i]` to a function (`self.done`). This function returns `None` by virtue of not having an explicit return statement.

When you do this:

```
allStars[i] = allStars[i]()
```

... You are replacing the value of `allStars[i]` with the result of calling `allStars[i]`, which is `None`. The next time this line of code executes, `allStars[i]` is `None`, so you get that error.

If you are trying to do animation, there are better ways than to have your own infinite loop running, since you already have an infinite loop running -- `mainloop`. For example, you can remove the entire while loop and try/catch block at the end of your code with the following:

```
def redraw():
    for i in range(len(items)):
        items[i] = items[i]()
    root.after(int(1000/30), redraw) # 30 frames per second

root.after_idle(redraw)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  In the blobs example, the author omits the mainloop function and uses the while loop.  I assumed it was for future considerations of synchronization, but this is just based loosely on what I've read about sync difficulties with Tkinter.  I am new to python so I'm mostly just following the author's example and not entirely understanding everything I'm doing yet.

Comment: "sync difficulties"? What does that mean? I didn't realize there was no invocation of `mainloop`. That is a very strange way to use Tkinter, and isn't recommended. The example you are using is a poor example of how to do animation with tkinter.

Comment: I can't find the particular reference, but people were basically stating a preference of pygame over tkinter because it handles synchronization automatically, whereas tkinter requires more careful attention.  I chose Tkinter because I personally prefer to use standard libraries where I can and the disadvantage (so I've read) for pygame is that it can be slow and clunky.  I'm not sure what I'd replace mainloop with.

Comment: by the way, do you know of a better animation example that uses better standards?

Comment: @Xurtio: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11505034/7432

Comment: Thank again for your input.  Just to be sure, if these animations will eventually become interactive (such as a game) is this still the correct approach; it appears you just put your listening events right before the frame redraw, correct?

Comment: @Xurtio: yes, this is the correct approach. Leveraging the event loop in this way allows the UI to remain responsive.