# I am trying to make Tkinter Canvas text of length x continuously scroll across a finite area <x

Tags: python, python-3.x, scroll, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make Tkinter Canvas text of length x continuously scroll across a finite area less than x.  I have multiple canvastext objects with different text.  If I print(newtext) it shows the scroll i want but it does not display during the running of the program.  I tried with a while True: loop and it never displayed the canvas at all.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
 text='really long text string that i want to scroll 15 characters at a time'

 canvastext=canvas.create_text(1,1,text=scrolltext(text),
 tag=(calmotag,booktag,'texttag'),width=20)

def scrolltext(text):
     textlength=15
     shorttext=tkinter.StringVar() 
     shorttext.set(text.get()[0:14])
     itemtext=text.get()
     if len(itemtext)>textlength:

         newindex=0
         endindex=newindex+14
         while endindex<len(itemtext)+2:
             oldtext=shorttext.get()
             oldindex=itemtext.index(oldtext)
             newindex=oldindex+1
             endindex=newindex+14
             newtext=itemtext[newindex:endindex]
             shorttext.set(newtext)
             root.update_idletasks()
             root.after(1000)
```

Comment: Don't do your animation with a `while` loop in tkinter. It's an antipattern. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11505034/7432

Comment: Thanks Bryan for the link.  It works perfectly.  I tried similar but with a for or while loop but was not getting the output desired.  As soon as I removed the loops and adjusted the code to change the text each scrolltext() callback it worked.