# How to make marquee on tkinter in label?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this source code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import time
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()


    def initialize(self):
        self.geometry('450x250+0+0')
        self.configure(background="#379DDB")
        self.title('Konversi Bilangan')
        **self.label = Label(self, text='Konversi Dari',font=('times',24,'italic'),bg="#379DDB")**
        self.label.pack()
        self.tombol=Button(self, text='Biner',font=(18),borderwidth='3px',width=10,command=self.OnButtonClick1,bg="#69ABD3")
        self.tombol.pack(side=TOP)
        self.tombol2=Button(self, text='Desimal',font=(18),borderwidth='3px' ,width=10, command=self.OnButtonClick2,bg="#69ABD3")
        self.tombol2.pack(side=TOP)
        self.tombol3=Button(self, text='Oktal',font=(18),borderwidth='3px' ,width=10,command=self.OnButtonClick3,bg="#69ABD3")
        self.tombol3.pack()
        self.tombol4=Button(self, text='Hexa',font=(18),borderwidth='3px' ,width=10,command=self.OnButtonClick4,bg="#69ABD3")
        self.tombol4.pack()
        self.tombol5=Button(self,text='Quit',font=(18),borderwidth='3px' ,width=10, fg='red', command= self.quit,bg="#69ABD3")
        self.tombol5.pack()
```

How to make marquee from that I bold? If it is not possible how to make marquee like vb in tkinter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simple animation using tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502879/simple-animation-using-tkinter)

Comment: See the linked question for a recipe on how to animate things in tkinter. In your case you would of course update the marquee instead of drawing an image.

Comment: @stefan please avoid posting your question twice. Wait patiently for someone to respond to you on your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern for doing animation in tkinter is to use `after` to schedule one frame of the animation at a time. It looks something like this, where `fps` is defined as the number of frames you want per second, and `widget` is a tkinter widget:

```
def animate():
    <draw one frame of animation>
    widget.after(int(1000/fps), animate)
```

As for a marquee, one of the easiest solutions is to use a canvas, since it has a convenient `move` method that can be used to move text from right to left.

Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Marquee(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, text, margin=2, borderwidth=1, relief='flat', fps=30):
        super().__init__(parent, borderwidth=borderwidth, relief=relief)

        self.fps = fps
        
        # start by drawing the text off screen, then asking the canvas
        # how much space we need. Use that to compute the initial size
        # of the canvas. 
        text = self.create_text(0, -1000, text=text, anchor="w", tags=("text",))
        (x0, y0, x1, y1) = self.bbox("text")
        width = (x1 - x0) + (2*margin) + (2*borderwidth)
        height = (y1 - y0) + (2*margin) + (2*borderwidth)
        self.configure(width=width, height=height)

        # start the animation
        self.animate()

    def animate(self):
        (x0, y0, x1, y1) = self.bbox("text")
        if x1 < 0 or y0 < 0:
            # everything is off the screen; reset the X
            # to be just past the right margin
            x0 = self.winfo_width()
            y0 = int(self.winfo_height()/2)
            self.coords("text", x0, y0)
        else:
            self.move("text", -1, 0)

        # do again in a few milliseconds
        self.after_id = self.after(int(1000/self.fps), self.animate)
        
root = tk.Tk()
marquee = Marquee(root, text="Hello, world", borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")
marquee.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, but there are a couple of things I don't understand. I'd appreciate some clarification.
  1. Why do we have to use tk.Canvas.__init__()? super().__init__() causes an error: AttributeError: 'Marquee' object has no attribute 'tk'
  2. If I print(self) it gives .!marquee. What does that mean? I have never seen that before.
  3. How the heck does this work - self.coords("text", x0, y0)? According to the documentation coords() "returns a list of coordinates for the object in ARGS". Yet we are using it to set the coordinates!!

Comment: Ah! I just found the answer to question 3 on effbot.

Comment: @SadSack963: whatever documentation you are reading appears to be incorrect. `Coords` is both for getting and setting the coordinates. `.!marquee` is the internal name of the widget. This was written before `super()` was common. However, when I use `super` in this code it works just fine for me. I've edited the answer to use `super()`

Comment: Many thanks Bryan. 
The tcl.tk web servers were down last night, so I couldn't check the docs there. I was just looking at the docstring on the coords() function itself, which does not mention setting the coords! The PyCharm linter issues a warning "Expected type 'float', got 'str' instead". For others looking for this info, see https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/canvas.html#M42
Regarding the .!marquee, from what I read the dot indicates the root window, but The exclamation mark remains a mystery. Not that it matters, I'm just intrigued.
Anyway, many thanks for posting this solution. :)

Comment: @SadSack963: "." represents the root window, and is also used as a separator for deeper hierarchies just like "/" both represents the root directory and is used as a separator for deeper hierarchies of files and directories. The "!" is just a character that tkinter adds to distinguish it's internally-created names from other names. There's nothing special about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be hard to integrate because tkinter doesn't *"play nice"* with infinite loops.

The below program [written with assistance from here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/464630/a-ticker-for-long-messages-python-tkinter) creates a marquee, this is simply an example to prove this can be done and is a poor way of doing this.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text="Lorem Ipsum"

text = (' '*20) + text + (' '*20)

marquee = Text(root, height=1, width=20)
marquee.pack()

i = 0

def command(x, i):
    marquee.insert("1.1", x)
    if i == len(text):
        i = 0
    else:
        i = i+1
    root.after(100, lambda:command(text[i:i+20], i))

button = Button(root, text="Start", command=lambda: command(text[i:i+20], i))
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This also uses the `Text` widget instead of the `Label` widget, mostly because it's simpler to do this way.

---

To start it on program launch, simply adjust it to the below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text="Lorem Ipsum"

text = (' '*20) + text + (' '*20)

marquee = Text(root, height=1, width=20)
marquee.pack()

i = 0

def command(x, i):
    marquee.insert("1.1", x)
    if i == len(text):
        i = 0
    else:
        i = i+1
    root.after(100, lambda:command(text[i:i+20], i))

command(text[i:i+20], i)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ohhh i get it now thank you root.after just so much easier

Comment: This isn't the right way to use `after`. This is no different than calling `sleep`.

Comment: @Rawing It's probably not the most elegant thing, but I think that it's a more tkinterish (tkinteric? tkintereric? tkinteresque?) solution now?

Comment: Yes, that's better. The convoluted lambda functions aside, you don't need to call `root.update()`. Also, we should clean up this wall of comments.

Comment: @Rawing This is about as much effort as I'm willing to put into a question where the OP has expended relatively little effort. Just figured it was worthwhile answering as I couldn't find another question relating directly to creating a marquee in tkinter.

Comment: how to running marquee like above without the button , so when it open it just running

Comment: @EthanField thanks for this answer but how you move the text in `textbox` from left. `Comment` your code for it to be easy to make changes it.

Comment: @OJOE I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. [You are welcome to suggest an edit to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47224514/edit).

Comment: @EthanField the are being displayed from right to left how can do it vice versa

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in Tkinter but I hope this will help you to understand to implement this in your code. Thanks!

```
import sys
import time


def main():
    program = animate()
    program.data = input("Enter string : ") + " "
    program.width = int(input("Enter width : "))
    program.animate()


class animate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = ""
        self.width = 0

    def animate(self):
        try:
            while True:
                for x in range(0, self.width):
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    msg = "\r{}{}".format(" " * x, self.data)
                    sys.stdout.write(msg)
                    sys.stdout.flush()

                for x in range(self.width, 0, -1):
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    msg = "\r{}{}".format(" " * x, self.data)
                    sys.stdout.write(msg)
                    sys.stdout.flush()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Exiting")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I do not know if you can use this code to make an imitation of the marquee, it should be noted that it is for a window of 800 x 600 if they are other measures just have to change the 805 by the measure of the width of your window.

```
class MarqueeAnimation:

  def __init__(self,master=None,text="",eje_x = 0,velocity = 0):
      self.root = master
      self.marqueetext = text
      self.posx = eje_x
      self.velocity = velocity
      #Marquee Label
      self.lbl = Label(self.root,text=self.marqueetext,font=(12))
      self.reqposx = self.lbl.winfo_reqwidth() * -1
      self.lbl.place(x=0,y=250)

  def StarAnimation(self):
      try:
         self.posx += 1
         self.lbl.update()
         self.lbl.place(x=self.posx,y=265)
         if self.posx == 805:
            self.posx = self.reqposx
         self.animation = self.root.after(10,self.StarAnimation)
      except:
         pass
  
   def ChangeAnimation(self,newtext=""):
      self.lbl.configure(text=newtext)
      self.lbl.update_idletasks()
      self.reqposx = self.lbl.winfo_reqwidth() * -1

   def StopAnimation(self):
      self.root.after_cancel(self.animation)
```